# AES C# File Encryption - stream writes only 16 bytes

Tags: c#, encryption, stream, aes

Here is piece of my code, which should encrypt file and write cryptograph into new file. Code is similiar to example found at Microsoft MSDN webpage.

```
byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[InputFileStream.Length];
byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[InputFileStream.Length];

InputFileStream.Read(inputBuffer, 0, (int)InputFileStream.Length);

ICryptoTransform encryptor = AesInstance.CreateEncryptor(AesInstance.Key, AesInstance.IV);


            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter encrypted = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {

                        encrypted.Write(inputBuffer);

                    }

                    outputBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    OutputFileStream.Write(outputBuffer, 0, (int)outputBuffer.Length);


                }

            }

OutputFileStream.Close();
InputFileStream.Close();`
```

The problem is that input buffer reads bytes from file correct, but output buffer seems to have only 16 bytes of data. The result is that output file has only 16 bytes, even if input file was large.
Where is the mistake? Problem exists on various modes, ECB, CBC, etc.

Comment: Don't worry about that, this is ensured in program logic.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old, but it deserves a better explanation. The problem is hidden in the `StreamWriter` itself. This class should be used for writing **text** into a stream. The `inputBuffer` is no text, however. It is a byte array!

`encrypted.Write(inputBuffer);`

is equal to

`encrypted.Write(inputBuffer.ToString());`

According to MSDN `StreamWriter.Write(object)`:

> Writes the text representation of an object to the text string or
>   stream by calling the ToString method on that object.

The correct solution is to write the input buffer directly into the `CryptoStream`:

```
using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream(outputBuffer))
{
    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
         csEncrypt.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
    }
    return msEncrypt.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you use

```
encrypted.Write(inputBuffer);
```

you are not giving the writer the size of buffer to write.

Comment: inputBuffer is a byte[] type, so I think it isn't necessary to give size of buffer, is it?

Comment: The main problem is that `StreamWriter` is a subclass of `TextStream` and you cannot write a `byte[]` buffer to it. Use a `MemoryStream` instead of that, and specify the buffer size for the `Write` function, and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of streams do buffering, especially crypto and compression streams. Don't call ToArray on the MemoryStream until you have closed/disposed the crypto stream.

```
            using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter encrypted = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    encrypted.Write(inputBuffer);
                }
            }
            OutputFileStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(),
                0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
        }
```

To be even clearer, lose the MemoryStream completely and just create the crypto stream on top of the OutputFileStream - this will work nicely even with huge data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly, i've got unhandled exception "Cannot access a closed Stream" at line with memoryStream.Lenght.
Also, when i've discarded memoryStream and used only CryptoStream, i'm still getting only 16bytes on output

Comment: @Anna hmm.... Does the crypto-stream constructor have an option to own / not-own the inner stream?

Comment: AFAIK cryptoStream constructor gets only one stream as parameter, "The stream on which to perform the cryptographic transformation".
I think that there could be problem with flushing streams, but IDK how to fix it, when using files...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is fixed now. Thanks to Marc response, i figured it out how should it work.
Here is working code, if anyone would need it later:

```
            InputFileStream.Read(inputBuffer, 0, (int)InputFileStream.Length);
            InputFileStream.Flush();
            InputFileStream.Close();

            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream(outputBuffer))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(inputBuffer);
                        swEncrypt.Flush();
                        swEncrypt.Close();
                    }
                    csEncrypt.Flush();
                    csEncrypt.Close();
                }
                OutputFileStream.Write(outputBuffer, 0, (int)outputBuffer.Length);
                OutputFileStream.Flush();
                OutputFileStream.Close();
            }
```

Maybe it isn't perfect code (i know it may be redundant) but it works fine even for huge files.